# PC busy icon has changed

Tags: windows

The busy icon has recently changed from the swirling blue circle to the sand timer, What has caused this change?
I have not tried to amend this problem because I don't know what to do. 
I am using windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Mouse cursors can be set by 3 ways. Through the `Control Panel` -> `Mouse` -> `Pointers`, from `Themes` and from `Accessibility options`.

Either must have been changed by you or someone else for this to occur.

You can easily change it back though by going to `Control Panel` -> `Mouse` -> `Pointers` and select a different theme or change them individually.